# How to call a contract method that accepts Enums as input with cast send

Tags: solidity, foundry, cast

I have the following `deploy` method:

```
function deploy(address admin, uint256 _salt, Type _type) public {
    bytes32 salt = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(bytes32(_salt), admin));
    address myContract;
    if (_type == Type.A) {
        myContract = address(new A{salt: salt}());
    } else if (_type == Type.B) {
        myContract = address(new B{salt: salt}());
    }
}
```

How do I call the contract with Foundry's cast?

Answer (score 1):

In Solidity, enums are represented by `uint8`.

Off the top of my head, I would use the following

```
cast send <contract_address> "deploy(address,uint256,uint8)" 0x3eC11316a0a436ed1BD5943481B3722D2fA4C2a4 2 1 --rpc-url=<rpc_url> --private-key=<private_key>
```

whereby,
`0x3eC11316a0a436ed1BD5943481B3722D2fA4C2a4` is an example for your `address`, `2` is an example for your `uint256` and `1` is an example for your `enum` parameter. Given your enum holds at least two fields, e.g. `Type.A` and `Type.B`, whereby, `Type.A` is passed via `0` and `Type.B` via `1`.